# How many items do I need to inspect given my population size?

Tags: sampling, binomial-distribution, sample-size

Hey just scratching my head with this problem:

If I have a process that produces say 10,000 items. Each item can either be correct or incorrect (pass or fail). How many items do I need to check to be 95% sure that all items are correct?

When performing these checks on this subset of items let's say I find an item that's incorrect. Now, how many items do I need to check to be 95% sure that all the remaining items are correct (given that I've found one incorrect item in the previous n checks)?

We can assume the items are independent and identically distributed.

Comment: I don't think you can ever get a boundary on such probability that's actually zero/one, outside of numerical precision issues. By the simple rule of 3, even if you observe 10,000 all-passes the upper 95% bound for failure in the hypothetical population is still 1 in 3,333. What I want to say is, you can get arbitrary confidence on some non-zero upper limit of failure with enough samples, but never certainty on it actually being zero (short of observing the full population).

Comment: @PBulls I think the OP means they want a confidence interval for these 10,000 items, not a super population.